# Android how to create vertical recyclerview with section header and horizontal recyclerview with section names(click to open its section position)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hi i want to create a recyclerview where it is divided into sections by category name. For example

```
[Category 1]     [Category 2]     [Category 3]   // buttons on image

Category 1 (section header)
->c1 product 1
->c1 product 2    (Products list of category 1)
->c1 product 3

Category 2 (section header)
->c2 product 1
->c2 product 2   
->c2 product 3    (Products list of category 2)
->c2 product 4

Category 3 (section header)
->c3 product 1
->c3 product 2   
->c3 product 3    (Products list of category 3)
->c3 product 4
->c3 product 5
```

I want to show all products in same recyclerview divided with headers and when scrolled to its section change selected category. also when category button clicked want to scroll to its section position. currently the product adapter changes product list on category button click

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView sub_category_rv;
    private RecyclerView products_rv;

    private Category_Adapter categoryAdapter;
    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> subCategoryList;

    private Product_Adapter productAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> productList;
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> productList1;
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> productList2;
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> productList3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sub_category_rv = findViewById(R.id.sub_category_rv);
        products_rv = findViewById(R.id.products_rv);

        subCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        subCategoryList.add(new CategoryModel("Category 1"));
        subCategoryList.add(new CategoryModel("Category 2"));
        subCategoryList.add(new CategoryModel("Category 3"));

        productList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        productList1.add(new ProductModel("c1 product 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 10.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList1.add(new ProductModel("c1 product 2", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 10.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList1.add(new ProductModel("c1 product 3", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 10.00", R.drawable.placeholder));

        productList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        productList2.add(new ProductModel("c2 product 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 15.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList2.add(new ProductModel("c2 product 2", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 15.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList2.add(new ProductModel("c2 product 3", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 15.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList2.add(new ProductModel("c2 product 4", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 15.00", R.drawable.placeholder));

        productList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        productList3.add(new ProductModel("c3 product 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 20.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList3.add(new ProductModel("c3 product 2", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 20.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList3.add(new ProductModel("c3 product 3", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 20.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList3.add(new ProductModel("c3 product 4", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 20.00", R.drawable.placeholder));
        productList3.add(new ProductModel("c3 product 5", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed.", "$ 20.00", R.drawable.placeholder));

        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.addAll(productList1);

        setCategoryRecyclerview();
        setProductRecyclerview();
    }

    public void setCategoryRecyclerview() {
        categoryAdapter = new Category_Adapter(this, subCategoryList, sub_category_rv, 0);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
        categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Category_Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
                productList.clear();
                if (position == 0) {
                    productList.addAll(productList1);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    productList.addAll(productList2);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    productList.addAll(productList3);
                }

                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        PaddingItemDecoration paddingItemDecoration_Product = new PaddingItemDecoration(15);
        sub_category_rv.addItemDecoration(paddingItemDecoration_Product);

        sub_category_rv.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        sub_category_rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    }

    public void setProductRecyclerview() {
        productAdapter = new Product_Adapter(this, productList, products_rv);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        productAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Product_Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCartAddClick(View itemView, int position) {

            }
        });
        if (products_rv.getItemDecorationCount() > 0) {
            products_rv.removeItemDecorationAt(0);
        }

        PaddingItemDecoration paddingItemDecoration_Product = new PaddingItemDecoration(15);
        products_rv.addItemDecoration(paddingItemDecoration_Product);

        products_rv.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        products_rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    }

}
```

**Category_Adapter**

```
public class Category_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Category_Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList;
    private Context context;
    private int defaultSelectedPosition = 0;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;
    private int previousPosition = -1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String TAG = "Category_Adapter";
    private View categoryView;


    public Category_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList, RecyclerView recyclerView,int defaultSelectedPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.defaultSelectedPosition = defaultSelectedPosition;
    }

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View itemView, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        categoryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_category_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(categoryView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        CategoryModel category = categoryList.get(position);
        TextView rv_category_name_tv = viewHolder.rv_title_tv;
        LinearLayout rv_linearlayout = viewHolder.rv_linearlayout;

        if (selectedPosition == -1) {
            if (defaultSelectedPosition == position) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(viewHolder.itemView, position);
                        previousPosition = selectedPosition;
                        selectedPosition = position;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            rv_linearlayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.rv_category_border_selected));
            rv_category_name_tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        } else {
            rv_linearlayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.rv_category_border_not_selected));
            rv_category_name_tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red));
        }

        rv_category_name_tv.setText(category.getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public LinearLayout rv_linearlayout;
        public TextView rv_title_tv;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Triggers click upwards to the adapter on click
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(itemView, position);

                            previousPosition = selectedPosition;
                            selectedPosition = position;
                            notifyItemChanged(previousPosition);
                            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            rv_linearlayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_linearlayout);
            rv_title_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_title_tv);

        }

    }


    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return selectedPosition;
    }

    public int getPreviousPosition() {
        return previousPosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
        this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    }
}
```

**Product_Adapter**

```
public class Product_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Product_Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> productList;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private static final String TAG = "Menu_Adapter";
    private View ProductView;


    public Product_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductModel> productList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.productList = productList;
        this.context = context;
        this.mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View itemView, int position);

        void onCartAddClick(View itemView, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ProductView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_product_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(ProductView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        ProductModel product = productList.get(position);

        TextView nameTextView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        TextView priceTextView = viewHolder.priceTextView;
        TextView descriptionTextView = viewHolder.descriptionTextView;
        ImageView productImageView = viewHolder.productImageView;

        nameTextView.setText(product.getTitle());
        priceTextView.setText(product.getPrice());
        descriptionTextView.setText(product.getDescription());

        productImageView.setBackgroundResource(product.getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView priceTextView;
        public TextView descriptionTextView;
        public ImageView productImageView;
        public LinearLayout addCartLinearLayout;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_menu_name_tv);
            priceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_menu_price_tv);
            descriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_menu_description_tv);
            productImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_menu_image_iv);
            addCartLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_add_cart_ll);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Triggers click upwards to the adapter on click
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(itemView, position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            addCartLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onCartAddClick(itemView, position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
public class ProductModel {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String price;
    private int image;

    public ProductModel(String title, String description, String price, int image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**CategoryModel**

```
public class CategoryModel {
    private String title;

    public CategoryModel(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**RV product item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rv_product_item_shape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_menu_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#2b2f4c"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
         />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_menu_description_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rv_add_cart_ll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_add_cart_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Add Cart"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rv_menu_price_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
              />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rv_menu_image_iv"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**RV category item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rv_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rv_category_border_not_selected"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Category 1 selected]
[image: Category 2 selected]